# Why does AWS cloudfront return Access denied even though the s3 bucket is public and s3 url is working fine

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I have an s3 bucket where I store some images these Images are publicly accessible. I have check the image URLs and here are the photos confirming that my bucket is publicly accessible

[image]

Now I would like to use cloudFront to serve this image.

I created a cloudFront with the following settings as shown in the picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After configuring the Cloudfront distribtion, I ensured the my Origin access identiy is reflected in my bucket policy here is my bucket policy

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity XXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BucketName/*"
    }
]
```

}

I create a signedUrl using the following code in nodejs

```
const signer = new AWS.CloudFront.Signer(cloudFrontAccessKeyId, cloudFrontPrivateKeyId);
console.log(cloudFrontAccessKeyId,cloudFrontPrivateKeyId," PRIVATE ")
const linkExpiration = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 100;

function returnCFsignedUrl(req) {
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    signer.getSignedUrl({
        url: `https://cloudfrontDomain/s3Key}`,
        expires: linkExpiration
    },(err,url)=>{
        if (err){
            reject(err);
        }else{
            console.log(url," URL ")
            resolve(url)
        }
    })
   
})
```

}

**I get a signed URL from this code which when clicked return access denied

- I tried to add `Access-Control-Request-Headers Access-Control-Request-Method Origin` as suggested by this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error/  but nothing seems to work**

Comment: Does your error response XML include `<RequestId>` and `<HostId>` or no?  If yes, S3 is denying the request; if no, CloudFront is denying the request.

Comment: There is no requestId or hostId if cloudfront is denying the response how can I debug it

Comment: `const linkExpiration = 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 100;` is incorrect.  This value should be a unix timestamp, not an interval.

Comment: ok I will double check it